# Difference between 'du' and 'du -b'?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, du, inode

```
root@host:/var/log/apache2# du access.log -bh
753M    access.log
root@host:/var/log/apache2# du access.log -h
1.2G    access.log
```

Why is there such a huge difference in size for the same file?

Comment: As for my current version of linux, -b and -h options conflicts. Please add details a bout your OS flavor. (kernel type, version, distribution, cure-utils, etc.)

Comment: without -h the values are in bytes thats it. The difference still remain the same.


OS: Ubuntu precise x86_64


$uname -a
Linux host 3.2.0-38-virtual #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 13 13:42:54 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


coreustils installed version 8.13-3ubuntu3.2

Comment: The version was here important. in my version of coreutils, "-b" meant just "bytes" just like "-k" is "kilobytes" and so on... which conflicts with "-h" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go. from [Precise Ubuntu Mangages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/du.1.html) :

```
       --apparent-size
              print apparent sizes,  rather  than  disk  usage;  although  the
              apparent  size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes
              in (`sparse') files, internal  fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,
              and the like

       -B, --block-size=SIZE
              scale  sizes  by  SIZE before printing them.  E.g., `-BM' prints
              sizes in units of 1,048,576 bytes.  See SIZE format below.

       -b, --bytes
              equivalent to `--apparent-size --block-size=1'
```

So not only do you have count in MiB/GiB on the first side, but you may have a "[sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file#Detection)" in front of you.

(I'm assuming here that you are using coreutil's `du`and not POSIX's)